# Django startproject creates broken projects

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.4

After installing Django 1.4.3 using pip on debian 6.0.6 (squeeze) `django-admin.py startproject` creates broken projects.

```
$ django-admin.py startproject testproject
$ cd testproject
$ python manage.py shell
Error: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

It seems that the project produced assumes a flat structure (like in 1.3) whereas it's formatted like a 1.4 project (with a testproject project app directory where settings.py actually is). If I do:

```
$ ln -s testproject/settings.py settings.py
```

`python manage.py shell` works just fine but I'm worried the project is broken in a more profound way.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling django and I've removed every other version of django that I could find on the system.

Importing django in python directly gives the following:

```
>>> django.get_version()
'1.4.3'
```

What could be causing this behavior and how would I go about fixing my installation of Django?

This is what's in my manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testproject.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Location of django-admin.py:

```
$ which django-admin.py
/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
```

I noticed that this django-admin.py was not identical to the one in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/bin/`. After replacing the one in `/usr/local/bin/` with that version the problem remained.

---

In `manage.py` changed the line `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testproject.settings")` into `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "testproject.settings"`. After doing this I could produce a shell without error.

Changing the template from which manage.py is copied (`/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/project_template/manage.py` in my case) in the same way has django-admin.py produce non-broken projects.

Comment: could you paste your manage.py ?

Comment: @Chris: my manage.py has been added

Comment: What's the output of `which django-admin.py ` at your shell?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: info added

Comment: I really smeels like you got several version of django playing with each others. This is why we use virtualenv. Before trying to solve a problem that may not be easily solvable, just use virtualenv.